# Opening directory with \ and ' in conjunction with each other

Tags: linux

I have a directory that I need to open called `Spice_Maple\'s_Copy`. I've tried several different methods with quotation wraps and I still have no success.

Any idea that could get this open?

Comment: Try tab-completion. Type `cd Spice_Maple` then press the `<Tab>` key.  The shell will complete the file name with appropriate escaping of characters.

Answer (score 3):

you will need to escape the "\" and " ' ":

```
cd Spice_Maple\\\'s_Copy
```

and the result will have 3 "\", the first two: "\" will make the shell read it as pure text "\", and the third "\" plus " ' " ( " \' " ) will make the shell read it as pure text " ' "

https://www.shellscript.sh/escape.html

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html

Comment: It's actually really odd, now that I'm looking closer. This directory is not coming up when I do `ls`. But I do see the directory in my FTP. 

I went ahead and tried that and it did not work.

Comment: try: ls -la, to see all the directoies, even hidden.

Comment: hidden directories in unix/linux start with " . " (dot) character

Answer (score 0):

You can just put it in double quotes and escape the backslash once, or what @LordPinkFloyd and escape each thing.

```
cd "Spice_Maple\\'s_Copy"
```

The single quote doesn't have special meaning inside double quotes, but the backslash still does.